# How to create multidimensional array for my playlist?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a playlist section for lyrics website.

For creating a tracklist, is multidimensional array is best way to input? I have two inputs in my MD-array that is song and other is artist corresponding to that. I can create a textbox dynamically using JS. Please help me to create MD-array and input in Db using looping. Please provide basic idea along with code I will modify it later.

```
    Tracks    |    Artist
    _____________________

    A         |    ar1
    B         |    ar2
    C         |    ar3
```

want somewhat this type of input to fill to DB.

Comment: is this how the data is saved in your database? in two columns

Comment: Yes this is the format.. I mean two of table columns in which I will input using MD-array.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have multidimensional arrays, but nested arrays. they simulate dimensions. there are also objects in which you can hold the data sets. so you must use arrays or objects =)

you can have your data in many forms in your array. for e.g.

```
$myarray = array(0=>array('artist'=>'someone','tracks'=>array(tracks...)),
                 1=>array(...));
```

Comment: These are the ways that I have already found on google for creating array, Please provide code with proper way that is using loop etc.

Comment: @Aditii what @Headshota has answered should be enough as starting step,people are not here to write code for you, but to help you.

Comment: I just want hint, to proceed coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic class you can use to use your database returned result as an array of object.

```
    <?php
/*
 * Default database class, stores connections and queries
 * and all does db interaction
 */
class Database {

    private static $connection;
    private static $current_query;


    function __construct() {
        // do something
    }

    public static function open_connection() {
        $db_server = 'localhost';
        $db_user = 'db_user';
        $db_pass = 'db_pass';
        $db_name = 'db_name';
        $connection = mysql_connect($db_server,$db_user,$db_pass);
        if (!$connection){
            // throw error
            die ("Connection to database failed: ". mysql_error() ." $db_server,$db_user,$db_pass"); // debug
        }

        $db_select = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection);
        if (!$db_select){
            // throw some error
            //die("Database selection Failed: " .mysql_error());
        }
        self::$connection = $connection;
    }

    public static function close_connection() {
        if (isset(self::$connection)){
            mysql_close(self::$connection);
            unset(self::$connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        if (!self::$connection){
            self::open_connection();
        }
        self::$current_query = $sql;
        try {
            $result = mysql_query($sql,self::$connection);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            self::close_connection();
            // throw custom error
            // The query failed for some reason. here is query :: self::$current_query
        }
        return $result;
    }


    private static function instantiate($record) {
        $obj = new self;
        foreach ($record as $k =>$value){
            $obj->$k = $value;
        }
        return $obj;
    }

    public static function find_by_sql($sql){
        if (!is_string($sql))
        return false;
        $result_set = self::query($sql);
        $obj_arr = array();
        while ($row = self::fetch_array($result_set))
        {
            $obj_arr[] = self::instantiate($row);
        }
        return $obj_arr;
    }

}
```

now to access your data

```
$playlist = Database::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM `playlist`");

// loop through your result
foreach($playlist as $play){
   echo "<p>$play->tracks : $play->artist</p>";
}
```

That makes it easier for you to interact with your results set, maybe you should study the find_by_sql() and the instantiate() methods
Goodluck :)